# Why does using new in a Dafny function give an error?

Tags: dafny

I am wondering why I am getting an error for the following program:

```
class KV 
{
  var key : int;
  var value : int;
  constructor (k: int, v: int) modifies this
  {
    this.key := k;
    this.value := v;
  }
}

function foo () : KV
{
   new KV(0,0)
}
```

I got: `invalid UnaryExpression` when I ran this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dafny `function`s are pure. They can depend on the heap, by giving a `reads` clause. But they cannot have side effects - they cannot modify the heap. Since your function `foo` has zero arguments and no `reads` clause, it must return the same value each time it is called. The memory allocation operator `new` gives a different value each time it is called, so can't be used in a function.

It is also important to note that Dafny functions are `ghost` by default. They are not executable at runtime. Rather they are used during the verification phase of compilation. If you want a non ghost function you must write `function method` instead of `function`.

You can use `new` inside a `method`. Methods are imperative procedures and do not need to be pure.

```
class KV 
{
  var key : int;
  var value : int;
  constructor (k: int, v: int) modifies this
  {
    this.key := k;
    this.value := v;
  }
}

method foo () returns (kv:KV)
{
   kv := new KV(0,0);
}
```